# How to make my app support for multiple screen with unique alignment of all elements present on screen?

Tags: android

i am doing a android application that having the table layout and buttons i want to support my app to multiple screens what is the precautions i have to take any help,thanks in advance

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

And this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html